# Перебор массива через цикл и вывод через функцию js

Tags: javascript, массивы

Мне нужно вывести сообщения `messagaes` с помощью `function`, путём перебора массива.
По итогу, в консоле должно вывестись примерно следующее:

administrator | Вы получили предупреждение за публикацию рекламы на форуме

Петр | Собираем встречу в субботу в 19:00. Придёшь?

и т.д

А сейчас выводит это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имя берётся из `from` в массиве `messagaes`, а текст сообщения из `text`

```js
let user = {
  name: "Иван Иванов",
  login: "killer504",
  reputation: 97,
  messages: [{
      from: "administrator",
      text: "Вы получили предупреждение за публикацию рекламы на форуме"
    },
    {
      from: "Петр",
      text: "Собираем встречу в субботу в 19:00. Придёшь?"
    },
    {
      from: "administrator",
      text: "Ваш рейтинг был повышен пользователем DonkeyKong"
    },
    {
      from: "administrator",
      text: "Ваш рейтинг был повышен пользователем Netologist"
    },
    {
      from: "Brian Kerninghan",
      text: "hello, world"
    }
  ]
};

console.log('Всего сообщений: ' + user.messages.length);

function msgs() {
  for (let i = 0; i < user.messages.length; i++) {
    console.log(user.messages);
  }
}

msgs(user.messages);
```

Comment: вот так попробуйте: `let i = 0; i < user.messages.length; i++`

Comment: @AjeetShah немного дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Технически, так:

```js
function formatAndPrint(messages) {
  messages.forEach(m => console.log(m.from + " | " + m.text))
}

const user = {
  name: "Иван Иванов",
  login: "killer504",
  reputation: 97,
  messages: [{
      from: "administrator",
      text: "Вы получили предупреждение за публикацию рекламы на форуме"
    },
    {
      from: "Петр",
      text: "Собираем встречу в субботу в 19:00. Придёшь?"
    },
    {
      from: "administrator",
      text: "Ваш рейтинг был повышен пользователем DonkeyKong"
    },
    {
      from: "administrator",
      text: "Ваш рейтинг был повышен пользователем Netologist"
    },
    {
      from: "Brian Kerninghan",
      text: "hello, world"
    }
  ]
};

console.log(formatAndPrint(user.messages));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let user = {
  name: "Иван Иванов",
  login: "killer504",
  reputation: 97,
  messages: [{
      from: "administrator",
      text: "Вы получили предупреждение за публикацию рекламы на форуме"
    },
    {
      from: "Петр",
      text: "Собираем встречу в субботу в 19:00. Придёшь?"
    },
    {
      from: "administrator",
      text: "Ваш рейтинг был повышен пользователем DonkeyKong"
    },
    {
      from: "administrator",
      text: "Ваш рейтинг был повышен пользователем Netologist"
    },
    {
      from: "Brian Kerninghan",
      text: "hello, world"
    }
  ]
};

console.log('Всего сообщений: ' + user.messages.length);

function msgs() {
  for (elem of user.messages) {
    console.log(`${elem.from} | ${elem.text}`);
  }
}

msgs();
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы оперировать данными в функции, их нужно туда передать как аргумент. Потому что функция ограничивает данные своей областью видимости

```
msgs(user.messages);
```

и функция

```
function msgs(messages) {
...
...
```

В функции обращаетесь по нужному индексу и ключу `messages[i].from` и `messages[i].text`

Comment: Немного дополнил вопрос

Comment: @realHikkan В функции обращаетесь по нужному индексу и ключу messages[i].from и messages[i].text ↑